# How to save data on same excel sheet from vba forms?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form which have various details like "User's Email" ,"Phone Number" etc.  I want whenever I click submit , these fields from data should get save on the same excel sheet and when next time I make any entry and save it , it should append the previous data with two line gaps.

I have this for now, which is working fine but I want whenever I make a new entry it should append with previous data.

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

ws.Range("A1") = " Troubleshooting Steps : " + Check1.Caption + vbCrLf + 
Check2.Caption + vbCrLf + Check3.Caption + vbCrLf + Check4.Caption + vbCrLf + Check5.Caption + vbCrLf + Check6.Caption

ws.Range("A3") = "Summary : " + txtNotes.Text

txtNotes.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: You can verify the last row used in a sheet with this: `LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` and then, the new range will be: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LastRow + 2)`.

Comment: I am new to this , so I am assuming to add 
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).En(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LastRow + 2)

at the end of my code like this , Am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert new data in a database with this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRange As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set LastRange = ws.Range("A" & LastRow + 2)

    'Conidering the Users email in column A, users phone in column B and users name in column C
    LastRange = UsersEmailTextBox.Text
    LastRange.Offset(0, 1) = UsersPhoneTextBox.Text
    LastRange.Offset(0, 2) = UsersNameTextBox.Text
    '...


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , it helped

Comment: @KarandeepSingh Just hit this answer as the right one. You're welcome.

Comment: I want every text to be displayed in a format which I am able to do to some extend but the issue I am facing now is showing the checked checkboxes in the file .
I modified your code a bit  to get them in just one cell in vertical way 

LastRange.Offset(1, 0) = " LAN ID : " + TextBox5.Text + vbCrLf + "Email : " + TextBox6.Text + vbCrLf + "Extension : " + TextBox7.Text + vbCrLf + "Alternate : " + TextBox8.Text + vbCrLf

Answer (score 0):

I want every text to be displayed in a format which I am able to do to some extend but the issue I am facing now is showing the checked checkboxes in the file .
I modified your code a bit  to get them in just one cell in vertical way

LastRange.Offset(1, 0) = " LAN ID : " + TextBox5.Text + vbCrLf + "Email : " + TextBox6.Text + vbCrLf + "Extension : " + TextBox7.Text + vbCrLf + "Alternate : " + TextBox8.Text + vbCrLf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch8T0.jpg)